# how to run .jar file in micro?

Tags: vba, jar

I have a .jar file to convert Excel into XML format. I want to have a button on the spreadsheet, when user click it, it will call. jar to convert the spreasheet. tried to use:

Shell ("C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java -jar XMLGenerator.jar")

it is not working, does anyone know how to do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass the file as a parameter of your program, like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java -jar XMLGenerator.jar yourFile.xls"
```